# 2-dimensional pointer to output a matrix

Tags: c++

I want to create a non-rectangular matrix that can output something like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

using 2-dimensional pointers.

I have a 1D pointer that points to an array which stores the size of each row : {6, 3, 4, 6, -1}.

-1 is a flag that will stop the while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<class T>
T** allocate(int* sizes) {

    T** twod; // 2-dimensional pointer

    while (*sizes != -1) { // the loop will stop when *sizes hit -1
        *twod = new T[*sizes];
        twod++;
    }

    return twod;
}

int main() {
    int array[] = {6,3, 4, 6, -1};
    int* sizes = array; // 1-D pointer to the array which stores the size of each row

    int** twod = allocate<int>(sizes);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < *(sizes+i); j++){
            twod[i][j] = 0;
            cout << twod[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The program doesn't output anything. Can you guys help me point out the problem here? I think it might have to do with the while loop.

Thanks a lot!

(This is an assignment of mine regarding the use of pointers. I have to use pointers to output something above. I know using static arrays are much easier)

Comment: In your `allocate` function you have a pointer `twod`, but nowhere do you make it actually point anywhere. That means the dereference will be invalid and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Not to mention the fact that in your `allocate` function you do `twod++` which means the pointer you return will be one *beyond* the end of any memory you make `twod` point to. You simply lose the original pointer (once you properly initialize it).

Comment: Lastly, whenever you think about "dynamic arrays", you next thought should *always* be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Oh and just to nitpick: A matrix is a fixed-size data structure with MxN elements. You're trying to create a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: @someprogrammerdude: Really appreciate the comments, but can you help me improve that line? I rewrote: T** twod = new int*[4] but there are no outputs still. And we are not allowed to use the vector library

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; sizes[i] != -1; ++i) { twod[i] = new T[sizes[i]]; }`

Comment: This is an awful assignment for understanding pointers given that pointers are *completely* unnecessary for this problem.

Comment: And a few quick *last* lastly points: In the `main`  function you don't need the pointer `sizes`, you can use `array` directly. Also, your loops to initialize and print the zeroes is wrong. I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And perhaps [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read through.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude: got it! Thank you! Can you explain why using the while loop is not efficient?

Comment: @someprogrammerdude: I put a note down under saying that the pointer "sizes" is a part of the assignment to understand pointer. Using static array can be more convenient tho

Comment: @PemiNguyen [Learn from a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c)

Comment: That's an awful way to do it. I'd use a vector of vectors. Anyways, create an array of pointers, where each pointers is a dynamically allocated array representing each row.

Comment: @blade -- Creating a vector of vectors is easy, but not cache friendly.  Creating each row dynamically, if you know the number of columns is a fixed size, is not a good way to do this, even though it is the way that is taught in books and school.  If the array is `M x N`, The memory will become fragmented, plus the overhead of having to call `new[]/delete[]` `M + 1` times.  It's better to allocate the entire pool of memory once (or twice for the pointers), and just point the array of pointers in the right spot in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not as what you expect just because your `allocate()` function is not logical.
You can try it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
T** allocate(int* sizes) 
{

   T** twod; // 2-dimensional pointer
   for(int i = 0;(*sizes)!=-1;i++)
   {
      twod[i] = new T[*sizes];
      sizes++;
   }
   return twod;
}
```